# How do I use arguments in a function that adds data to a table in sqlite3?

Tags: python, database, ubuntu, sqlite

I want to define a function with arguments which adds data to a table in sqlite3.

I am following a tutorial on youtube, which is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-vsdfCBpsU

I did the same thing, and had no problems until I decided to put in some arguments:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    #c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot(unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(names TEXT, floats REAL, ints INTEGER, personalities TEXT)')

def data_entry(name, float, int, personality):
    #c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES(8010, '2016-01-02', 'Python', 8)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO info VALUES(name, float, int, personality)")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()

create_table()

ref = [25,35,45,55,65,78,89,90]
for i in range(5):
    for j in ref:
        data_entry(j, .888, i, 'kind')
```

In the `data_entry` function, the "name" inside the parentheses of VALUES() apparently causes this error:

> OperationalError: no such column: name

I am doing this for an analysis of a simulation, so I'd be dealing with lots of lines of data in the database, which needs to be done using a function like this

Comment: Your create statement creates a column named `names`, whereas your insert, insert into `name`

Comment: if you look at the commented out lines of code (original, what I copied from youtube), it's different but it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use bind variables to pass values. If you change your insert execute to be

`c.execute("INSERT INTO info VALUES(?,?,?,?)", [name, float, int, personality])`

it should work. This tells it to insert the values and and swaps the '?' for the values in the list passed to execute.

Also, as someone noted in the comments you need to decided if you want the column to be 'name' or 'names' and then change the queries accordingly.

And as a last note, you really shouldn't use `float` and `int` as variable names. They are data types so it can be confusing.

*Edit* this should work. made some improvements. I added a finally block to close the connection. This way even if there is an error the connection will be closed. There is def a cleaner way to write this, but this should work at least.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    #c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot(unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(names TEXT, floats REAL, ints INTEGER, personalities TEXT)')

def data_entry(name, float, int, personality):
    #c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES(8010, '2016-01-02', 'Python', 8)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO info VALUES(?,?,?,?)", [name, float, int, personality])
    conn.commit()



try:
    create_table()

    ref = [25,35,45,55,65,78,89,90]
    for i in range(5):
        for j in ref:
            data_entry(j, .888, i, 'kind')
except:
    raise
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Comment: It says: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor.

Comment: get rid of the c.close() and move the conn.close() out of the function, and put at the end of the the script. you cant close the connection and then use the connection again.

Comment: sadly there's another error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: What line throws that error? it is working fine for me.

Comment: Hey, it worked!! turns out i just missed a comma before the "[" . thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL command in data entry won't work. You're not actually providing any values to insert, and you're not defining which columns to use.

A proper insertion with sqlite3 would look something like this:

```
to_sql_dict = {
    "name": name,
    "float": float,
    "int": int,
    "personality": personality 
}
SQL = """INSERT INTO info (
        names, floats, ints, personalities
    ) VALUES (
        :name, :float, :int, :personality
    )"""

c.execute(SQL, to_sql_dict)
```

This is the proper way to do it. A simpler way involves SQL-only, but is advised against as it is supposedly susceptible to SQL injection attacks:

```
SQL = """INSERT INTO info (
        names, floats, ints, personalities
    ) VALUES (
        {}, {}, {}, {}
    )""".format(name, float, int, personality)
c.execute(SQL)
```

Either way should work, but as I mentioned you should try to get it to work the first way.

PS. Note on column names: it's generally not common practice to use plurals. 
EDIT: Code.

Comment: I'm not really usin this for a website - this is just one time use for some scientific data analysis so security is not a big deal, but I'll try your code and let you know what happens asap, thanks for the help

Comment: @sneedshelp Don't worry about it, Jacobr's answer is as secure as my first one, but also more concise. FYI, the sql vulnerability is just in having a direct string injection (imagine giving the argument "personality = x; DROP TABLE info" to the function) . However, I maintain that it's a useful practice for debugging because you can read your SQL exactly.